# Is there a way to simulate multithreading in DOS, e.g., when solving the dining philosopher's problem?

Tags: multithreading, assembly, x86, dos, dining-philosopher

The dining philosophers problem is a classic computer science textbook problem for demonstrating the use of multithreading. As [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem):

> Five silent philosophers sit at a round table with bowls of spaghetti. Forks are placed between each pair of adjacent philosophers.
>
> Each philosopher must alternately think and eat. However, a philosopher can only eat spaghetti when they have both left and right forks. Each fork can be held by only one philosopher and so a philosopher can use the fork only if it is not being used by another philosopher. After an individual philosopher finishes eating, they need to put down both forks so that the forks become available to others. A philosopher can only take the fork on their right or the one on their left as they become available and they cannot start eating before getting both forks.
>
> Eating is not limited by the remaining amounts of spaghetti or stomach space; an infinite supply and an infinite demand are assumed.
>
> The problem is how to design a discipline of behavior (a concurrent algorithm) such that no philosopher will starve; i.e., each can forever continue to alternate between eating and thinking, assuming that no philosopher can know when others may want to eat or think.
>
> The problem was designed to illustrate the challenges of avoiding deadlock, a system state in which no progress is possible.

In summary, then, this is a classical problem in multithreading, demonstrating the need to avoid resource starvation using mutual exclusion principles.

I want to implement such a program in real-mode DOS, but DOS clearly lacks multithreading capabilities.

I am aware of third-party software such as [RTKernel](http://www.on-time.com/rtkernel-dos.htm), but this seems like overkill for this situation.

Is there any solution to simulate multithreading so that I can program a simulation of the dining philosophers problem in DOS, using 16-bit x86 assembly language?

Comment: FWIW: DOS doesn't offer any help to multi-threaded programming, but it also doesn't do anything to _prevent_ you from writing a multi-threaded program. A program running on a DOS box has full control of the hardware. I don't know RTKernel, but I bet its not "overkill." Providing multi-threading probably is a large part of what RTKernel does. If you want to write your own multithreading implementation, you'll probably spend a lot more time making that work than you will spend on the actual dining philosophers.

Comment: @SolomonSlow  About the time spent on writing my own multithreading implementation, you're right that it took longer than writing a *basic version* of the dining philosophers, but as it happens I went for a *deluxe version*. The multithreading module is but a tiny part of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Multithreading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)#Multithreading) is about creating the illusion that multiple execution paths in a program run simultaneously. On today's [multi-core computers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-core_processor) this doesn't have to be an illusion anymore if the number of threads stays within limits.

### A different road to multithreading

In the [preemptive multitasking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_(computing)#Preemptive_multitasking) model the running out of a timeslice triggers a thread switch. The switch is initiated from outside the running thread.
In the multithreading module that I have written, the switch can not happen without the running thread's approval and collaboration.
It is the running thread that decides where, **but not when**, a switch can take place. To this end the programmer has to insert `call`s to a function *MaybeYieldThread* at strategically chosen places in the thread. Loops are good places for this.
If at the moment of such a call, the timeslice has not yet elapsed then the call will instantly return. If the timeslice has elapsed then the *MaybeYieldThread* momentarily acts like a true *YieldThread* and the switch happens.

The major advantage of this approach is that it can avoid many of the [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Software) for which you would normally be using synchronization objects like mutexes, semaphores, or critical sections. You insert your `call MaybeYieldThread` instruction(s) where it is thread-safe and that's it!

### The main characteristics

The multithreading capabilities are encoded in a single source file *mtModule.INC* that you include in your application anywhere you like.

- small footprint. The include file has less than 600 bytes.
- very fast. Thread switches are inexpensive.
- wide range of allowable stacksizes. They can range from 128 to 65536 bytes in increments of 16 bytes.
- optimal memory use. Very little overhead and an allocator that coalesces free blocks.
- selectable timeslice. The timeslice can range from 1 to 55 msec. (55 uses standard 54.925494 msec)
- [round robin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_scheduling#Process_scheduling) scheduler.
- just a few, easy to use functions.
- very generous parameter passing scheme. Every (integer) register that is not used as an arg by the api itself is indeed a parameter on the thread's first invocation.

### The api description

The api that I propose is a small one, but I believe it delivers all the multithreading capability a DOS program could need...
At some moment I had implemented features like thread handles, thread priorities, and inter thread communication. In retrospect and bearing in mind the saying "Less is More", I am glad that I removed all of these.

It all starts with a `call` to *BeginSessionThread*. You define the borders of the session memory where all of the thread's stacks will be placed, you define the timeslice to be used, and you point to the first thread that immediately receives control if no errors were encountered.

Among the things that the first thread will do is creating additional threads using *CreateThread*. What you provide is the code address of the other thread and the amount of memory you wish to use for its stack.

Once threads are up and running, they can use *YieldThread* to give up control in favor of the next thread, use *MaybeYieldThread* to give up control if, and only if, the timeslice that they are running in has elapsed, and use *SleepThread* to give up control and remove themselves from being scheduled until the requested duration is over.

If a thread has outlived its purpose, a `call` (or `jmp`) to *ExitThread* or a mere `ret` instruction (from a balanced stack of course!) removes the thread permanently from the scheduler and returns the memory that its stack occupied, to the pool of free session memory.

When no more multithreading is needed, a `call` (or `jmp`) to *EndSessionThread* will return control to the instruction directly below from where the session was started (the `call BeginSessionThread` instruction). It is possible to pass an exitcode.
Alternatively, exiting from the last active thread will also end the session, but in this case the exitcode will be zero.

In order to suspend the multithreading session, you can call *StopSessionThread*. It will reset the timer frequency to the standard 18.2 Hz and freeze all pending SleepTimes. To resume the multithreading session, all it takes is a `call` to *ContSessionThread*.
Suspending the session is one way to temporarily pause the program without disturbing the SleepTimes.
And if you want to EXEC a child program or even launch a nested multithreading session, suspending the current session is mandatory for success.

### The api quick reference

```
BeginSessionThread
 Input
  BX timeslice in milliseconds [1,55]
  CX requested stacksize for first thread
  DX near address of first thread
  SI para address begin session memory
  DI para address end session memory
  -- everything else is user defined parameter
 Output
  CF=0 Session has ended, AX is SessionExitcode
  CF=1 'Insufficient memory'
       'Invalid stacksize'
       'Invalid timeslice'
 --------------------------------------
CreateThread
 Input
  CX requested stacksize for thread
  DX near address of thread
  -- everything else is user defined parameter
 Output
  CF=0 OK
  CF=1 'Invalid stacksize'
       'Out of memory'
 --------------------------------------
SleepThread
 Input
  CX is requested duration in milliseconds
 Output
  none
 --------------------------------------
MaybeYieldThread
 Input
  none
 Output
  none
 --------------------------------------
YieldThread
 Input
  none
 Output
  none
 --------------------------------------
ExitThread
 Input
  none
 Output
  none
 --------------------------------------
EndSessionThread
 Input
  CX is SessionExitcode
 Output
  none
 --------------------------------------
StopSessionThread
 Input
  none
 Output
  none
 --------------------------------------
ContSessionThread
 Input
  none
 Output
  none
 --------------------------------------
```

### Some points of interest

It is mandatory that a thread doesn't change the `SS` segment register and that it leaves about 80 bytes on the stack for use by the *mtModule.INC*.
For optimal 'preemptiveness', you should not use *MaybeYieldThread* too sparsely. On the other hand for efficiency reasons, you should perhaps not be using *MaybeYieldThread* in a tight loop.

```
; mtModule.INC Multithreading in DOS (c) 2020 Sep Roland
; ------------------------------------------------------
; assemble with FASM, compatible with CMD and DOSBox

; Functions:
;  BeginSessionThread(BX,CX,DX,SI,DI,..) -> AX CF
;  CreateThread(CX,DX,..) -> CF
;  SleepThread(CX)
;  MaybeYieldThread()
;  YieldThread()
;  ExitThread()
;  EndSessionThread(CX)
;  StopSessionThread()
;  ContSessionThread()

; Session header:
;  +0  wSessionHighMem
;  +2  wSessionNumberOfThreads
;  +4 dwSessionParentStackptr
;  +8  wSessionTickVarStep
; +10  wSessionMicroTimeslice
; +12  wSessionTickVar

; Thread header:
;  +0  wThreadLowMem
;  +2  wThreadStacksize
;  +4  wThreadStatus: DEAD/FREE (-1), AWAKE (0), ASLEEP (1+)
;  +6  wThreadStackptr
; --------------------------------------
; IN (bx=0,cx,dx,ss:si,fs) OUT (ax,CF) MOD (cx,si,di,bp,ds,es)
mtAlloc:cmp     cx, 4096                ; Max 64KB stack
        ja      .NOK
        cmp     cx, 8                   ; Min 128 bytes stack
        jb      .NOK
; Find a free alloc that is big enough
        mov     ax, fs
        inc     ax                      ; Skipping session header
.a:     mov     ds, ax
        cmp     [bx+4], bx              ; ThreadStatus
        jge     .b                      ; Is occupied
        mov     bp, [bx+2]              ; ThreadStacksize (size of free alloc)
        sub     bp, cx
        jae     .OK
.b:     add     ax, [bx+2]              ; ThreadStacksize
        cmp     ax, [fs:bx]             ; SessionHighMem
        jb      .a
.NOK:   stc
        ret
.OK:    je      .c                      ; Tight fit, no split up
; Init header of a free alloc
        add     ax, cx
        mov     ds, ax
        mov     [bx], fs                ; ThreadLowMem
        mov     [bx+2], bp              ; ThreadStacksize
        mov     word [bx+4], -1         ; ThreadStatus = FREE
        sub     ax, cx
        mov     ds, ax
; Init thread header
.c:     mov     [bx], fs                ; ThreadLowMem
        mov     [bx+2], cx              ; ThreadStacksize
        mov     [bx+4], bx              ; ThreadStatus = AWAKE
        imul    di, cx, 16              ; -> DI is total stacksize in bytes
        sub     di, (32+8+4)+2+2        ; Initial items that go on this stack
        mov     [bx+6], di              ; ThreadStackptr
; Init thread stack
        mov     es, ax
        mov     cx, (32+8+4)/2          ; GPRs, SRegs, EFlags
        cld
        rep movs word [di], [ss:si]
        mov     [di], dx                ; ThreadAddress
        mov     word [di+2], ExitThread
        inc     word [fs:bx+2]          ; SessionNumberOfThreads
        clc
        ret
; --------------------------------------
; IN (bx,cx,dx,si,di,..) OUT (ax,CF)
; BX timeslice in milliseconds [1,55] (55 uses standard 54.925494 msec)
; CX requested stacksize for first thread, DX near address of first thread
; SI para address begin session memory, DI para address end session memory
;
; CF=0  Session has ended, AX is SessionExitcode
; CF=1  'Insufficient memory' or 'Invalid stacksize' or 'Invalid timeslice'
BeginSessionThread:
        pushfd                          ; '..' Every register is considered
        push    ds es fs gs             ; parameter on the first invocation
        pushad                          ; of the thread
; Test parameters
        mov     bp, di                  ; SessionHighMem
        sub     bp, si                  ; ThreadLowMem
        jbe     mtFail
        dec     bp
        jz      mtFail
        dec     bx                      ; Timeslice in msec
        cmp     bx, 55
        jnb     mtFail
        inc     bx
; Turn MilliTimeslice BX into TickVarStep AX and MicroTimeslice CX
        mov     ax, 65535               ; Standard step is 'chain always'
        mov     cx, 54925               ; Standard slice is 54925.494 microsec
        cmp     bx, 55
        je      .a
        push    dx                      ; (1)
        mov     ax, 1193180 Mod 65536   ; TickVarStep = (1193180 * BX) / 1000
        mul     bx                      ; BX = [1,54]
        imul    cx, bx, 1193180/65536
        add     dx, cx
        mov     cx, 1000
        div     cx                      ; -> AX = {1193, 2386, ..., 64431}
        imul    cx, bx                  ; -> CX = {1000, 2000, ..., 54000}
        pop     dx                      ; (1)
; Init session header
.a:     xor     bx, bx                  ; CONST
        mov     ds, si                  ; -> DS = Session header
        mov     [bx], di                ; SessionHighMem
        mov     [bx+2], bx              ; SessionNumberOfThreads = 0
        mov     [bx+4], sp              ; SessionParentStackptr
        mov     [bx+6], ss
        mov     [bx+8], ax              ; SessionTickVarStep
        mov     [bx+10], cx             ; SessionMicroTimeslice
        ;;mov     [bx+12], bx           ; SessionTickVar = 0
; Init header of a free alloc
        mov     [bx+16], ds             ; ThreadLowMem
        mov     [bx+18], bp             ; ThreadStacksize, all of the session
        mov     word [bx+20], -1        ; ThreadStatus = FREE          memory
; Create first thread
        mov     fs, si                  ; ThreadLowMem -> FS = Session header
        mov     si, sp                  ; -> SS:SI = Initial registers
        mov     cx, [ss:si+24]          ; pushad.CX
        call    mtAlloc                 ; -> AX CF (CX SI DI BP DS ES)
        jc      mtFail
        mov     [cs:mtTick+5], fs       ; ThreadLowMem
        mov     [cs:mtChain+3], cs      ; Patch far pointer
        call    mtSwap                  ; Hook vector 08h/1Ch
        jmp     mtCont
; --------------------------------------
; IN (ss:sp)
mtFail: popad                           ; Return with all registers preserved
        pop     gs fs es ds             ; to caller
        popfd
        stc
        ret
; --------------------------------------
; IN (cx,dx,..) OUT (CF)
; CX requested stacksize for thread, DX near address of thread
;
; CF=0  OK
; CF=1  'Invalid stacksize' or 'Out of memory'
CreateThread:
        pushfd                          ; '..' Every register is considered
        push    ds es fs gs             ; parameter on the first invocation
        pushad                          ; of the thread
        xor     bx, bx                  ; CONST
        mov     fs, [ss:bx]             ; ThreadLowMem -> FS = Session header
        mov     si, sp                  ; -> SS:SI = Initial registers
; Coalescing free blocks
        mov     ax, fs
        inc     ax
.a:     mov     ds, ax                  ; -> DS = Thread header
        mov     bp, [bx+2]              ; ThreadStacksize
        cmp     [bx+4], bx              ; ThreadStatus
        jge     .c                      ; Is occupied
        mov     es, ax
.b:     add     ax, bp                  ; BP is size of a free alloc
        cmp     ax, [fs:bx]             ; SessionHighMem
        jnb     .d
        mov     ds, ax
        mov     bp, [bx+2]              ; ThreadStacksize
        cmp     [bx+4], bx              ; ThreadStatus
        jge     .c
        add     [es:bx+2], bp           ; ThreadStacksize, BP is size of
        jmp     .b                      ;    the free alloc that follows
.c:     add     ax, bp                  ; BP is size of an actual thread stack
        cmp     ax, [fs:bx]             ; SessionHighMem
        jb      .a
.d:     call    mtAlloc                 ; -> AX CF (CX SI DI BP DS ES)
        jc      mtFail
; ---   ---   ---   ---   ---   ---   --
; IN (ss:sp)
mtFine: popad                           ; Return with all registers preserved
        pop     gs fs es ds             ; to caller
        popfd
        clc
        ret
; --------------------------------------
; IN (cx) OUT ()
; CX is requested duration in msec
SleepThread:
        pushf
        pusha
        push    ds
        xor     bx, bx                  ; CONST
        mov     ds, [ss:bx]             ; ThreadLowMem -> DS = Session header
        mov     ax, 1000                ; TICKS = (CX * 1000) / MicroTimeslice
        mul     cx
        mov     cx, [bx+10]             ; SessionMicroTimeslice
        shr     cx, 1                   ; Rounding to nearest
        adc     ax, cx
        adc     dx, bx
        div     word [bx+10]            ; SessionMicroTimeslice
        mov     [ss:bx+4], ax           ; ThreadStatus = TICKS
        pop     ds
        popa
        popf
        jmp     YieldThread
; --------------------------------------
mtTick: push    ds                      ; 1. Decrement all sleep counters
        pusha
        xor     bx, bx                  ; CONST
        mov     ax, 0                   ; SMC Start of session memory
        mov     ds, ax                  ; ThreadLowMem -> DS = Session header
        mov     cx, [bx+8]              ; SessionTickVarStep
        stc
        adc     [bx+12], cx             ; SessionTickVar
        pushf                           ; (1)
        mov     dx, [bx]                ; SessionHighMem
        inc     ax
.a:     mov     ds, ax                  ; -> DS = Thread header
        mov     cx, [bx+4]              ; ThreadStatus
        dec     cx
        js      .b                      ; AX was [-1,0], ergo not ASLEEP
        mov     [bx+4], cx              ; ThreadStatus
.b:     add     ax, [bx+2]              ; ThreadStacksize -> End current stack
        cmp     ax, dx
        jb      .a
        mov     byte [cs:$+23], 90h     ; 2. Turn 'MaybeYield' into 'Yield'
        popf                            ; (1)
        popa
        pop     ds
        jc      mtChain
        push    ax
        mov     al, 20h
        out     20h, al
        pop     ax
        iret
mtChain:jmp far 0:mtTick                ; 3. Chain to original vector 08h/1Ch
; --------------------------------------
; IN () OUT ()
MaybeYieldThread:
        ret                             ; SMC {90h=nop,C3h=ret}
; ---   ---   ---   ---   ---   ---   --
; IN () OUT ()
YieldThread:
        mov     byte [cs:$-1], 0C3h     ; Back to 'MaybeYield'
        pushfd                          ; Save context current thread
        push    ds es fs gs
        pushad
        xor     bx, bx                  ; CONST
        mov     ax, ss                  ; Begin current stack
        mov     ds, ax                  ; -> DS = Thread header
        mov     [bx+6], sp              ; ThreadStackptr
        mov     fs, [bx]                ; ThreadLowMem -> FS = Session header
        sti                             ; Guard against every thread ASLEEP!
.a:     add     ax, [bx+2]              ; ThreadStacksize -> End current stack
        cmp     ax, [fs:bx]             ; SessionHighMem
        jb      .b
        mov     ax, fs                  ; Session header
        inc     ax                      ; Stack lowest thread
.b:     mov     ds, ax
        cmp     [bx+4], bx              ; ThreadStatus
        jne     .a                      ; Is DEAD/FREE (-1) or ASLEEP (1+)
; ---   ---   ---   ---   ---   ---   --
; IN (ax,bx=0)
mtCont: mov     ss, ax
        mov     sp, [ss:bx+6]           ; ThreadStackptr
        popad                           ; Restore context new current thread
        pop     gs fs es ds
        popfd
        ret
; --------------------------------------
; IN () OUT ()
ExitThread:
        xor     bx, bx                  ; CONST
        dec     word [ss:bx+4]          ; ThreadStatus = DEAD/FREE
        mov     ds, [ss:bx]             ; ThreadLowMem -> DS = Session header
        dec     word [bx+2]             ; SessionNumberOfThreads
        jnz     YieldThread             ; Not exiting from the sole thread
        xor     cx, cx                  ; SessionExitcode
; ---   ---   ---   ---   ---   ---   --
; IN (cx) OUT (ax,CF=0)
EndSessionThread:
        call    mtSwap                  ; Unhook vector 08h/1Ch
        xor     bx, bx                  ; CONST
        mov     ds, [ss:bx]             ; ThreadLowMem -> DS = Session header
        lss     sp, [bx+4]              ; SessionParentStackptr
        mov     [esp+28], cx            ; pushad.AX, SessionExitcode
        jmp     mtFine
; --------------------------------------
; IN () OUT ()
StopSessionThread:
ContSessionThread:
        push    ax
        mov     ax, [ss:0000h]          ; ThreadLowMem -> AX = Session header
        mov     [cs:mtTick+5], ax       ; ThreadLowMem (In case there's been a
        pop     ax                      ;                       nested session)
; ---   ---   ---   ---   ---   ---   --
; IN () OUT ()
mtSwap: push    ds
        pushad
        xor     bx, bx                  ; CONST
        mov     ds, bx                  ; -> DS = IVT
        mov     ax, [046Ch]             ; BIOS.Timer
.Wait:  cmp     ax, [046Ch]
        je      .Wait
        cli
        mov     ds, [cs:mtTick+5]       ; ThreadLowMem -> DS = Session header
        mov     [bx+12], bx             ; SessionTickVar = 0
        mov     dx, [bx+8]              ; SessionTickVarStep
        mov     ds, bx                  ; -> DS = IVT
        mov     bl, 1Ch*4               ; BH=0
        inc     dx                      ; SessionTickVarStep
        jz      .Swap
        dec     dx
        mov     bl, 08h*4               ; BH=0
        mov     ax, cs
        cmp     [cs:mtChain+3], ax
        je      .Hook
.Unhook:xor     dx, dx
.Hook:  mov     al, 34h
        out     43h, al
        mov     al, dl
        out     40h, al
        mov     al, dh
        out     40h, al
.Swap:  mov     eax, [bx]
        xchg    [cs:mtChain+1], eax
        mov     [bx], eax               ; Hook/Unhook vector 08h/1Ch
        sti
        popad
        pop     ds
        ret
; --------------------------------------
```

### An example application

Next demo program uses every function available in the above api. Its sole purpose is to demonstrate how to use the api functions, nothing more.
It's easy to experiment with different timeslices because you can specify the length of the timeslice (expressed in milliseconds) on the commandline.
The program runs fine in true real address mode and under emulation (Windows CMD and [DOSBox](https://www.dosbox.com/)).

[image: Different types of multithreading]

```
; mtVersus.ASM Multithreading in DOS (c) 2020 Sep Roland
; ------------------------------------------------------
; assemble with FASM, compatible with CMD and DOSBox
DefaultTimeslice=55                     ; [1,55]

        ORG     256

        mov     sp, $
        cld

; Was timeslice specified on commandline ?
        xor     cx, cx                  ; RequestedTimeslice
        mov     si, 0081h               ; Commandline
Skip:   lodsb
        cmp     al, " "
        je      Skip
        cmp     al, 9
        je      Skip
Digit:  sub     al, "0"
        jb      Other
        cmp     al, 9
        ja      Other
        cbw
        imul    cx, 10                  ; Reasonably ignoring overflow
        add     cx, ax
        lodsb
        jmp     Digit
Other:  mov     bx, DefaultTimeslice
        cmp     cx, 1
        jb      Setup
        cmp     cx, 55
        ja      Setup
        mov     bx, cx
Setup:  mov     di, [0002h]             ; PSP.NXTGRAF -> end of session memory
        lea     si, [di-128]            ; 2KB session memory (11 threads)
        mov     dx, Main
        mov     cx, 8                   ; 128 bytes stack

        mov     bp, MsgCO
        call    BeginSessionThread      ; -> AX CF
        jc      Exit
        mov     bp, MsgPE
        call    BeginSessionThread      ; -> AX CF
        ;;;jc      Exit

Exit:   mov     ax, 4C00h               ; DOS.Terminate
        int     21h
; --------------------------------------
; IN (bp)                               ; BP=ModeOfOperation
Main:   mov     dx, bp                  ; Displaying title
        mov     ah, 09h                 ; DOS.PrintString
        int     21h

        mov     di, EOF                 ; Preparing output string
        mov     cx, 79
        mov     al, " "
        rep stosb
        mov     word [di], 240Dh        ; CR and '$'

        mov     di, EOF+6               ; Creating 10 counting threads
        mov     dx, Count
        mov     cx, 8                   ; 128 bytes stack
.a:     mov     byte [di], "0"
        call    CreateThread            ; -> CF
        jc      EndSessionThread        ; CX=8
        add     di, 8
        cmp     di, EOF+79
        jb      .a

        mov     byte [Flag], 0
        mov     dx, 10                  ; Sleep while counters run (10 sec)
.b:     mov     cx, 1000
        call    SleepThread
        mov     ah, 01h                 ; BIOS.TestKey
        int     16h                     ; -> AX ZF
        jz      .c
        mov     ah, 00h                 ; BIOS.GetKey
        int     16h                     ; -> AX
        call    StopSessionThread
        mov     ah, 00h                 ; BIOS.GetKey
        int     16h                     ; -> AX
        call    ContSessionThread
.c:     dec     dx
        jnz     .b

        not     byte [Flag]             ; Forces all other threads to exit
        call    YieldThread

; Exiting from the sole thread == EndSessionThread
        mov     dl, 10
        mov     ah, 02h                 ; DOS.PrintChar
        int     21h
        ret                             ; == ExitThread
; --------------------------------------
; IN (di,bp)                            ; DI=Counter, BP=ModeOfOperation
Count:  mov     si, di                  ; Position of the ones in our counter
.a:     mov     al, [si]
        inc     al
        cmp     al, "9"
        jbe     .b
        mov     byte [si], "0"
        dec     si
        cmp     byte [si], " "
        jne     .a
        mov     al, "1"
.b:     mov     [si], al
        mov     dx, EOF
        mov     ah, 09h                 ; DOS.PrintString
        int     21h
        cmp     bp, MsgPE
        je      .PE
.CO:    call    YieldThread
        cmp     byte [Flag], 0
        je      Count
        jmp     ExitThread
.PE:    call    MaybeYieldThread
        cmp     byte [Flag], 0
        je      Count
        ret                             ; == ExitThread
; --------------------------------------
MsgCO:  db      13, 10, '10 seconds of cooperative multithreading '
        db      'using YieldThread():', 13, 10, '$'
MsgPE:  db      13, 10, '10 seconds of preemptive multithreading '
        db      'using MaybeYieldThread():', 13, 10, '$'
Flag:   db      0
; --------------------------------------
        INCLUDE 'mtModule.INC'
; --------------------------------------
EOF:
; --------------------------------------
```