# How to run two (or more) procedure at the same time in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, procedure

I want to do a timer in my game, but while the timer is shown, I need the game to keep moving, and I can't do it right now because it will do the timer, and just after it is finished it will start the game. is there any option to call the game procedure and the timer procedure at the same time?

Comment: With multiple threads on a multi-core system, yes, multiple functions can be running truly simultaneously.  But that's hard, and not possible on computers with a single CPU core.  The usual technique is to realize that computers are *fast*, and can do lots of stuff in the time between screen refreshes, including updating a time *and* drawing the game.  This is why computers have hardware timer interrupts and stuff, so you can manage time without just running a loop that counts iterations.

Comment: Either read the system clock and calculate the elapsed time each frame, or create threads. Threads can run on a single core, but it's quite inefficient due to context switching.

Comment: My recommendation is don't go for the thread option, but if you want to, the way to do it is the same as in C. You tagged `x86-16`, and I'd be surprised if there's any 16-bit x86 system with thread support. In this case, you can implement your own threads for fun, or just use the system clock.

Comment: Maybe in 32-bit windows running a 16-bit DOS executable, the program can create windows threads. I'd like to know if this is possible.

Comment: If you study the technique from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63101012/is-there-a-way-to-simulate-multithreading-in-dos-e-g-when-solving-the-dining, you'll be able to run the game together with an independently functioning timer. It will take some effort, but you can achieve a lot...